# CMD: поиск устройств в сети по первым цифрам MAC-адреса

Tags: windows, сеть, cmd, bat

Мне нужно найти IP-адреса устройств в локальной сети по первым цифрам их MAC-адресов. Нашёл такое решение:

```
@echo off
:top
:: Loop through arp table entries and look for my device's MAC address
for /f "tokens=1-5 skip=3" %%f  in ('arp -a') do (
if "%%g"=="xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx" set ip=%%f
)

if "%ip%"=="" (
    echo Discovering network...
:: Ping all IPs from 192.168.0.1 to 254
    for /L %%N in (1,1,254) do start /b ping -n 1 -w 200 192.168.0.%%N >nul
    timeout 1 >nul
    goto :top
) else (
    echo Device found found: %ip%
)
pause
```

Но данный пример ищет только по полному совпадению MAC-адреса и выводит IP только первого найденного устройства. Как доделать этот пример, чтобы можно было находить по первым нескольким цифрам MAC-адреса все подходящие IP-адреса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получил ответ на англоязычном сайте stackoverflow, который мне помог:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001354/cmd-search-ips-of-devices-with-special-mac

```
@echo off
:: метка
:top
:: удаляем переменную, чтобы не мешала при следующем вызове функции
set "ip=" 
:: ищем подходящий MAC-адрес из arp-таблицы
for /f "tokens=1" %%f  in ('arp -a^|find " d4-85-64"') do set ip=%%f

:: если не нашли, пингуем все IP в заданном диапазоне и повторяем поиск
if "%ip%"=="" (
    echo Discovering network...
:: пингуем всех от 192.168.0.1 до 254
    for /L %%N in (1,1,254) do start /b ping -n 1 -w 200 192.168.0.%%N >nul
    timeout 1 >nul
    goto :top
)
:: возвращаем IP
echo Device found: %ip%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы можно было находить по первым нескольким цифрам MAC-адреса

```
if "%%g" GEQ "XX-XX" (if "%%g" LSS "XX-XX?" (echo Наш случай!))
```

> все подходящие IP-адреса

Запишите их во временный файл и перебирайте его заново для каждого МАС из ARP.

Comment: Я не силён в синтаксисе функций командной строки. Попробовал запустить пример на своём компе, но программа не выводит сообщение "Наш случай!", хотя искомый MAC-адрес точно есть в списке: if "%%g" GEQ "50-c2" (if "%%g" LSS "50-c2?" (echo Ура!))

Comment: `SetLocal EnableExtensions` не забыли?

Comment: Забыл, добавил @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion - не помогло

Comment: Мне тут предложили использовать find: in ('arp -a^|find "02-50-c2"') do, но столкнулся с тем, что find не находит нужную строчку. И вообще странно ищет. Только если в поиске 3 символа, и менее, например, 02-, а 02-50 - уже не находит...